# Add a SharePoint FieldDescription to an custom form

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm working on an existing custom list form that has some fields added without their corresponding SharePoint:FieldDescription.

Is there a way I can add these in Sharepoint Designer 2007, without having to manually code it? I realise this is a newby question but am hoping that someone can help out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Customize the new form or edit form or display form using SharePoint designer 2007. By default when the list custom new form web part is added, it will have field description controls.

follow this blog for customizing the new form: http://sharepoint07.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/customize-the-newformaspx/

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes this works most of the time. However I have found that if you have a custom list form with a field that has no field description it does not update. Even if you remove the field and then add it again via the data source details, the description still doesn't get added.